# Inserting data into database on postman

Tags: api, rest, postman

I've been creating a database and I've been using postman to insert new data. So  I wrote in the Body section:

```
{
    "Title":"Mr.",
    "First_Name":"Kevin",
    "Last_Name":"Maguire",
    "Mobile":"0895731889",
    "Email":"kevin.maguire@gmail.com",
    "Address_Line1":"9 Oldspark",
    "Address_Line2":"Blessington Road",
    "Town":"Naas",
    "County_City":"Kildare",
    "EIRCODE":"AB535657"
    "Manufacturer":"Sony"
    "Model":"Xperia",
    "Price":"255.00"
}
```

And pressed sent for the POST command, however, the outcome and what is inserted into MongoDB is this:

```
{
    "_id": "609af9f305f47930445892f6",
    "createdAt": "2021-05-11T21:41:07.792Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-05-11T21:41:07.792Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I just don't understand, it supposed to show the inserted data.

The code is here:
[Create and Save User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LBRC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't necessarily something that can be answered without seeing some code from the endpoint you're hitting or the object itself, but there's some likely issues that will hopefully help you find what's wrong.

Assuming you're hitting the endpoint you are intending to, and you have your postman input/output settings correct for whatever it is you're testing, the issue is likely in the controller you're using or the object.

Check to make sure you're returning what you think you're returning in your code. If you want to see the object, you should be returning the new object. This could look something like `return repo.save(newObj);`. Also, ensure that your object has gets for all of the data you are attempting to receive back here from it. If you don't have a way to get a field of the object, it wont be able to put it in the JSON for you.

Also I don't think its what you're doing but just in case, if you made a wrapper object or specifically created JSON to be returned, ensure that JSON or wrapper object actually contains everything you want to see back and is being created correctly.

If you don't need the information and you just want to see if the object was in fact created, you can try hitting another endpoint and do an action using the new object (if such an endpoint exists in your project). That said, you should likely still find the source of the issue at hand.